# Delete Duplicate Users Folder Catalina

Tags: terminal, catalina

Due to issues while upgrading to Catalina a duplicate users folder was created on my system. This folder is named "Users 1" and is ~85gb. I tried deleting it using `sudo rm -rf "Users 1"` but get `Read-only file system`. How do I get around this security measure to delete the folder?

Comment: Have you tried to just delete the content of `Users 1` instead of the directory itself? If you run `cd /Users\ 1; df .`, which disk and which mount point is shown?

Comment: Output: `/dev/disk1s5  489825072 199852136  15920768    93% 1542500 2447582860    0%   /`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went to the genius bar and the genius booted from an external volume and was able to see both Catalina partitions as volumes. From here it was as simple as moving the "Users 1" folder to the trash and emptying the trash. This can most likely be accomplish through target disk mode as well.